# Using Hotswap Agent with JBoss (Jboss Developer Studio)

Tags: java, jboss, jboss7.x, hotswap

The tutorial here: http://www.hotswapagent.org/quick-start

says to use:

```
-XXaltjvm=dcevm -javaagent:PATH_TO_AGENT\hotswap-agent.jar
```

as command line arguments.

However, when running my servlet on JBoss, from the JBoss developer studio, how do I pass in these arguments?

At a first look, it may be something with `eclipse.ini/config.ini`, but the IDE jvm spawn a new jvm for the JBoss server, does it pass arguments from the `.ini` to that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Double click to open server configuration

[image: Server Configuration]

Click to open dialog below

[image: Server Configuration Launch]

finally add or edit your vm arguments.

Comment: thanks a lot! now I get a Invalid option '-XXaltjvm=dcevm' :) but at least I got over this phase and learned dsomething

Comment: @Adrian3873 Check this: `download latest release of DCEVM Java patch and launch the installer (e.g. java -jar installer-light.jar). Currently you need to select correct installer for Java major version (7/8).` and `"Install DCEVM as altjvm" button. Java 1.7+ versions are supported.`

Comment: Thanks again. I already did that. But the solution was another: initially I was in a rush and entered the new arguments in the Program arguments, not in the VM arguments. Now it's starting but hangs up in debug mode; in release it starts, but in the link from my post at step 3 it says debug mode. Does Hotswap Agent only work in debug? Another silly question: what does step 4 mean: save a changed resource and/or use the HotSwap feature of your IDE to reload changes (what feature in my IDE? does it replace the .class file after auto-compilation by itself?)